# TYPO3: News Detail View on Microsites

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x, tx-news

I am working with the extension news on TYPO3 9.5. I have a project with few microsites and I want to use the news there. In the microsite homesite news(list) works but when I click the link which points to a detailed view of news, this leads to 404 and it does not work.

Detailed view does not work on Microsite.

I tried configuring Starting Point without success. Do i have to configure categories?

Any idea where I can also check?

Comment: Where is your detail view placed for the mircosites? Within their tree? Or have you one detailpage for all pages, so the page is *not* part of each pagetree?

Comment: The Detail View is inside microsite Tree. Each microsite has a Detail View Page. Data is outside the microsite Tree, in the main root Site.

Comment: Please show us a link to a news on the detail page that gets generated by the news list and the configuration of the news plugin on the detail page.

Answer (score 0):

The Solution was to change TCA to "unique" (TYPO3 Core Routing) due to URL resolving.
More can you find here:

https://forge.typo3.org/issues/91397#note-12